# Recovered user and organization unit wit out Membership of Exchange Server, why?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, mailbox

I just recovered a user and OU back to my domain on my Windows Server 2008 R2, using these directions:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379509%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

However once i reset the users password, I noticed Membership to Exchange 2010 Server is gone. Once the membership for Exchange 2010 is reestablished for that user, I still could not find the mailbox. So how do I recover a mailbox from Exchange Server for a user that was recovered?

Comment: Why the negative rating?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front and/or there's very little for someone here to go on to assist you.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: There are multiple different sets of directions there. Did you use the tombstone reanimation method using `ldp.exe` or did you restore the object using the AD Recycle Bin cmdlets?

Answer (score 1):

As [this previous page in the Recycle Bin instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379542(v=ws.10).aspx) notes:

> You can use Active Directory Recycle Bin to restore all deleted objects that were previously stored in AD DS. However, if you use Active Directory Recycle Bin to restore deleted Group Policy objects (GPOs) or Exchange-related objects that were previously stored in AD DS, **any application-specific data for these objects that was not stored in AD DS will not be restored**.

Since the relationship between a mailbox and a user is defined by the ownership information on the mailbox (ie. information stored in Exchange), The Active Directory Recycle Bin does not restore this relationship.

When a user is deleted in Active Directory, the mailbox will be marked as *disonnected* before being removed completely, look into reconnecting the mailbox instead of hammering your head against Active Directory: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123490(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Worse yet is that he probably didn't restore it with the recycle bin. He just used LDP.exe to reanimate the tombstone.